Poetry install is throwing error even toml file has reference for Python 3.10version
When I do poetry install then I'm getting below error:-
poetry install
Warning: In a future version of Poetry, PyPI will be disabled automatically if at least one custom source is configured with another priority than 'explicit'. In order to avoid a breaking change and make your pyproject.toml forward compatible, add PyPI explicitly via 'poetry source add pypi'. By the way, this has the advantage that you can set the priority of PyPI as with any other source.
The currently activated Python version 2.7.18 is not supported by the project (^3.10).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Creating virtualenv my-pipelines-components-e6az2al8-py2.7 in /home/nairv/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs

failed to query /usr/bin/python2.7 with code 1 err: '  File "/home/nairv/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 24\n    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(["", *os.environ.get("PATHEXT", "").lower().split(os.pathsep)]))\n                                          ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n'

I have python 3.10 installed and in my .toml file as well I have mentioned this Python version then why it is still referring to python2.7? How to remove that 2.7 reference and fix this issue?
my myproject.toml snippet:-
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-pipelines-components"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Pipelines Components"
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{ include = "src"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


I had to create a virtual python environment to solve this issue finally
